# Data won't insert into Database [php][pdo]

Tags: php, pdo

I've currently been trying to make it where it inserts the data of the current ticket that is being placed but it won't insert.

```
function insertTicketSubmission($title, $subject, $question)
{
    global $database;
    global $error;

    $sth = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO `tickets` (`TicketId`, `PlayerId`, `Title`, `Subject`, `Question`, `Date`, `Status`) VALUES (:TicketID, :PlayerID, :Title, :Subject, :Question, GETDATE(), Pending)");
    $sth->bindParam(":TicketID", generateRandomString());
    $sth->bindParam(":PlayerID", $_SESSION["userId"]);
    $sth->bindParam(":Title", $title);
    $sth->bindParam(":Subject", $subject);
    $sth->bindParam(":Question", $question);
    if($sth->execute())
    {
        $error = sendError("success", "Your Ticket has been submitted.");
    }
}
```

There's no errors at all but just won't insert into the table.

Comment: `Pending` is a string?

Comment: `pending` !== `:pending`

Comment: And you are not binding a `pending`

Comment: And you are not looking for errors

Comment: If `Pending` should be the default value just set that on the column definition (or quote it here to make it work currently).

Comment: Set `$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and errors will flow from the force Luke

Comment: You mean I should be Binding `Status`? Pending is just a placeholder for that column.

Comment: You aren't binding it and it is not a placeholder.

Comment: Also `generateRandomString`, why do that? Random is not unique, use an auto-incrementing column.

Comment: Gotcha! After you mentioned the default value for the column what i'm doing is pointless.

Comment: and I already have a auto-incrementing column which is called `id`

Comment: What is the `TicketId` in that case? You can have overlaps with this current approach which would argue that you don't have an `id` there.

Comment: basically for users to view there Tickets ?ticketId=ewqeubwqeee

Comment: Yes, but it is not unique so 2 DB records could have the same `ticketId`.

Comment: Unless you have it where it checks to not duplicate the ticketID

Comment: and it still doesn't insert the Ticket for some reason after doing what the other dude said.

Comment: Use the `@` to direct comments to people. Notifications aren't sent otherwise. Update the question with your new code. Also you have enabled error reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The issue was cause of the `GETDATE()` function.